# Best practice to include C++ libraries on my project

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake

I am facing some problems related to how to handle C++ projects. I have a set of repositories all of the tracked with git (hosted on gitlab).

- `repo_A`: my current project
- `repo_B`: a library I have created and need to use in `repo_A`

**Which is the best practice to include `repo_B` in `repo_A`?**.

1. Installing `repo_B` at system level? And then use `repo_B` from `repo_A` by using the CMakelists
2. Adding `repo_B` as submodule on `repo_A`
3. Adding it in the CMakeLists by using something similar to what is explained in the [googletest repository](https://github.com/google/googletest)

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

   project(googletest-download NONE)

   include(ExternalProject)
   ExternalProject_Add(googletest
   GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
   GIT_TAG           master
   SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
   BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
   BUILD_COMMAND     ""
   INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
   TEST_COMMAND      ""
   )
   ```

We are were originillay intalling libraries at user level. However, after starting to use Jenkins we are facing some problems.

Comment: Topology used when you have a project that depends on other (sub)projects varies greatly.  I find that having each project and (sub)project in a root directory as peers, and each peer project contains its own independent git repository works best for me and my work style.

Comment: *cough cough* `git submodules` *cough cough*

Comment: Their is no best practice. They all are different for different lib kinds and teams. To my taste the gtest practice is awful and for in-house libs, which are tightly related to the project, the submodules approach works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be a kind of mixed version. I usually track the external libraries as git submodules (in PROJECT_ROOT/submodules) and create a generic CMake file for all of them like this:

```
find_package(GTest)

if(GTEST_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "googletest was found!")
else()
  message(STATUS "googletest was not found, local build is needed!")

  include(ExternalProject)

  ExternalProject_Add(googletest-project
    URL ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/submodules/googletest/
    PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ext/googletest"
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_GTEST=ON 
      DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
    LOG_INSTALL ON
  )

  ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest-project install_dir)
  ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest-project source_dir)

  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${install_dir}/include)

  add_library(gtest STATIC IMPORTED)
  add_library(gtest_main STATIC IMPORTED)

  set_property(TARGET gtest PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
    ${install_dir}/lib/libgtest.a)
  set_property(TARGET gtest_main PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
    ${install_dir}/lib/libgtest_main.a)

  set_property(TARGET gtest APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
    ${install_dir}/include)
  set_property(TARGET gtest_main APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
    ${install_dir}/include)

  add_dependencies(gtest googletest-project)
  add_dependencies(gtest_main googletest-project)

  set(GTEST_LIBRARIES gtest)
  set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES gtest_main)

  set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS ${install_dir}/include)
endif()
```

This way googletest will not be built when it is already installed on your system (e.g. in a Docker image with all the external dependencies pre-installed). As you can see, I build googletest from the submodule directory and will not clone from github.